# Logging in different files with logback sharing packages

Tags: java, logback

I have a batch application which executes two different logic depending on the parameter passed. My application uses Spring and I want to log in different log files each of this "different processes". 
As the classes are in different packages, I configured in logback.xml file the loggers to use its own appender

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <configuration>

   <!-- Referencia: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html -->

   <!-- Propiedades de configuracion -->
   <property resource="batch.properties" />

   <!-- Appenders: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html -->

 <!-- pattern: %date [%thread] %-5level %logger - [%file:%line] - %message%n -->

<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="appender1" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
   <File>${log.dir}/batch-${HOSTNAME}.log</File>

<encoder>
  <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%n</pattern>
</encoder>

<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
  <minIndex>1</minIndex>
  <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
  <FileNamePattern>${log.dir}/batch-${HOSTNAME}.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>

<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
  <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>
 </appender>

<appender name="appender2" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <File>${log.dir}/batch-${HOSTNAME}.log</File>

 <encoder>
   <pattern>%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%n</pattern>
 </encoder>

 <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
  <minIndex>1</minIndex>
  <maxIndex>10</maxIndex>
  <FileNamePattern>${log.dir}/batch-${HOSTNAME}.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
</rollingPolicy>

<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
  <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>
</appender>

<!-- Levels  -->
 <logger name="my.process1" level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="appender1">/
 </logger>
 <logger name="my.process2" level="INFO">
<appender-ref ref="appender2">/
  </logger>
  <logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/>
  <logger name="org.springframework" level="WARN" />
   <logger name="com.ibm" level="INFO"/>

 <!-- Root -->
 <root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
 </root>
```

But I want to log Spring information too, but "only" in the file of the process it's executing. How should I configure that?

Thanks

EDIT: posted my actual logback.xml. I know that with that configuration spring is not logging in any file, but I dont know how to configure it to log only in one.

Comment: can you improve and give a more concrete example?

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to use a [Sifting Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) for the spring logging. I'm not sure yet whether MDC as deciding factor would work though, that depends on how your application works.